# Definition of spinor connection.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold with a spin structure. I want to understand how the connection on the spinor bundle is defined. I have read the follwing: "The Levi-Civita connection on the bundle of oriented orthonormal frames lifts to a connection on the spinor bundle". 
I want to know: What exactly is meant by "lifts"? I know that connections are defined as horizontal distributions on fiber bundles. What does it mean to lift a distribution?

Comment: If $E$ is the $\text{Spin}(n)$ bundle and $E'$ the frame bundle, then you can decide what the distribution up above is by saying that $v$ is in the distribution iff $dp(v)$ is in the distribution downstairs.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(X,g)$ be a Riemann manifold of dimension $m$, and $Spin(X)$ a spin structure on the tangent bundle, which is a $Spin(m)-$principal bundle. Let $S_m$ be a complex representation of $Spin(m)$:$$\rho:Spin(m)\to GL(S_m,\mathbb{C}).$$
Denote $S^{TX}=Spin(X)\times_{\rho}S_m\to X$ the associated complex vector bundle, and call it the spinor fiber. Recall the natural map
$$\lambda:Spin(m)\to SO(m)$$.

> [spinor connection]$\nabla$ a parallel affine connection on $TX\to X$, then locally $\nabla=d+\Gamma$, where $\Gamma\in\Omega^1(\mathfrak{so}(TX))$, so $d+d\rho(d\lambda)^{-1}(\Gamma)$ define a connection on $S^{TX}\to X$.